# Why does adding $watch in two controllers break my digestion loop?

Tags: angularjs

So I know how to fix my issue. But I would like to understand why it was an issue in the first place so I understand the fundamentals.

In the following Ajs code when I placed

```
$scope.$watch('city', function(){ //To watch for when the value changes on the FE and then changes when applicable.
       cityService.city = $scope.city;
});
```

in my forecastCtrl too, it broke my digestion loop for the city variable. Why is that? My FE is a simple text input with the city field defaulted to New York, NY on the homepage. Then my forecast page calls the variable to display it with a string.

```
        var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);

    weatherApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
              templateUrl:'pages/home.htm',
              controller:'homeCtrl'
              })

        .when('/forecast', {
              templateUrl:'pages/forecast.htm',
              controller:'forecastCtrl'
              });
    });

    weatherApp.service('cityService', function(){
       this.city = 'New York, NY'; //Default variable

    });

    weatherApp.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'cityService', function($scope, cityService){
        $scope.city = cityService.city; //To introduce city to scope or else it wont be reconginzed in the controller.

        $scope.$watch('city', function(){ //To watch for when the value changes on the FE and then changes when applicable.
            cityService.city = $scope.city;
        });

    }]);

    weatherApp.controller('forecastCtrl', ['$scope', 'cityService', function($scope, cityService){
        $scope.city = cityService.city; //To introduce city to scope or else it wont be reconginzed in the controller.

    }]);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? something like https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig for example?

Comment: What is your proposed fix?

Comment: Ah yes! Forgot to mention that it was actually saying it couldn't find the service 'cityService'.

And now when I try to reproduce the console error, it actually works fine, which is weird. All i did before to fix it was to remove the second $watch function from being defined in the forecastCtrl.

Comment: This might have been an error in brackets that didn't pick up my code successfully when I tried to create the local environment.